# Python seaborn - remove label border

Tags: python, graph, label, seaborn

I need to remove the light gray label border (upper left corner) and leave only the blue line and "Winter". I can't use matplotlib due to task conditions, so I need to use only seaborn. [This is my graph:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2KSj.png)
This is the part of my code for graph styling:

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(5,5)})
sns.set_style("whitegrid", {"axes.edgecolor": ".0", "axes.facecolor":"none"})
ax = sns.lineplot(x = "Year", y = "Temp", data = df, color='#538be6', label="Winter")
ax = ax.set(xlabel='', ylabel='Temperature[°C]')
```

Comment: You could try `seaborn.set_style(..., {...., 'legend.frameon':False})`

Comment: @JohanC doesn't work for me. i think its because i dont have legend at all, i have only label and i dont know how to make legend here

Comment: Well, this light gray border is the frame of the legend, and the blue line with the 'winter' label is the legend.  Did you edit it as `sns.set_style("whitegrid", {"axes.edgecolor": ".0", "axes.facecolor":"none", "legend.frameon":False})`?  And have that before the call to `sns.lineplot(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

As commented by JohanC, setting `'legend.frameon':False` does the trick but it must be included in `sns.set(rc={...})`.

```
import numpy as np      # v 1.19.2
import pandas as pd     # v 1.1.3
import seaborn as sns   # v 0.11.0

np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Year=np.arange(1952, 2015),
                       Temp=np.random.uniform(-12.2, 0.1, 63)))

sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(5,5), 'legend.frameon':False})
sns.set_style("whitegrid", {"axes.edgecolor": ".0", "axes.facecolor":"none"})
ax = sns.lineplot(x = "Year", y = "Temp", data = df, color='#538be6', label="Winter")
ax.set(xlabel='', ylabel='Temperature[°C]');
```

[image: winter]